Library/TeX directory doesn't exist after installing MacTeX
I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.4 and installed the latest MacTeX version. The installation went okay, but no TeX directory shows up in Library although it should.
When I'm running which latex or which pdflatex, it gives the path like /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin/latex, so I guess at least it's installed.
The problem is when I use LaTeX in python matplotlib, I keep getting error that latex cannot be found.
Is there anyone having the same problem?

Welcome! Have you logged out and in again?

What does ls /Library/TeX return in Terminal, and what does ls /etc/paths.d return?

Oh, never mind! I tried to delete it and reinstalled it few times and it seems now I have Library/TeX directory and no longer get error with matplotlib, although I still don't know what the problem was :( Thank you!
